# Where are the variables for 'addtocart_form.tpl.php' defined?

Tags: variables, joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I would like to specifically know where the variables `$product_parent_id` and `$product_id` are coming from.

I have created a second file titled addtocart_form2.tpl.php and would like for it to read from a second set of variables (i.e. `$product_parent_id2`, `$product_id2`)
I have gone to shop.product_details.php and created the variable `$product_id2` as pretty much a second instance of `$product_id`, but updated accordingly in its own set of database variables (if that makes any sense).

I just want to know **where these variables are defined** so I can alter the sources.

```
list($html,$children) = $ps_product_attribute->list_attribute( ( $product_parent_id > 0 )  ? $product_parent_id : $product_id );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$product_id** and **$product_parent_id** are also in **shop.product_details.php**

line 35:

> $product_id = intval( vmGet($_REQUEST, "product_id", null) );

line 78:

> $product_parent_id = (int)$db_product->f("product_parent_id");

(in VM 1.1.9)